# result when __all__ is not defined in __init__.py of package?

Tags: python, mkv

I am just learning and practicing python,on the way,i am reading about python packages and how to import into other modules or package at [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) ,I assume the following scenario ,

I have package as ,

```
Video/
    __init__.py
    formats/
        __init__.py 
        mkv.py  
        mp4.py
    length/
        __init__.py
        morethan20min.py
        lessthan20min.py
```

and in no

```
__init__.py
```

I have not defined

```
__all__
```

what happens if i have an import statement as,

```
import Video.format.mkv
import Video.formats.*
```

Since I have already imported mkv module in first statement,what exactly happens after execution of second import statement,I didnt get the concept after reading on the mentioned link.

Comment: The correct name is `__init__.py`, not `__init.py__`.

Comment: You won't get an error, its just redundant you either get everything from Video.format or you get something specific. It's like saying I want just one person, but you then take everyone. So no point in taking the one person in the first place.

Comment: Also, you can't do `import Video.formats.*`. `*` imports only work with the `from` form of the import statement.

Comment: But they have mentioned like,If __all__ is not defined, the statement import Video.format.*  does not import all submodules from the package Video.format into the current namespace;

Comment: okay gt it..Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
from whatever_package import *
```

first, if the package's `__init__.py` hasn't been run yet, it will be run. (If you've already done `import whatever_package.something_specific`, the package's `__init__.py` will have already been run.)

Then, if `whatever_package.__init__` does not define an `__all__` list, the import will pick up all *current* contents of the `whatever_package` object*. That'll be anything defined in `__init__.py` and any submodules that have already been explicitly imported by any code that has executed in your program. For example, if `whatever_package`'s `__init__.py` is empty, you do

```
import whatever_package.something_specific
from whatever_package import *
import whatever_package.other_thing
```

and no other import statements relating to `whatever_package` exist in your program, then the `import *` will pick up `something_specific`, but not any other submodules of `whatever_package`, such as `other_thing`.

---

*excluding anything that begins with an underscore, as is standard for any `import *` with no `__all__` list, whether you're importing from a package or a normal module.

Comment: What happens if `something_specific.__init__` is not empty

Comment: @user6654733: The import will pick up anything defined by `__init__.py`.

Comment: @user6654733: then what is the advantage of having * notation in import statement?it is useful only when we define `__all__`??

Comment: It's pretty much never useful. You should pretty much never use `from x import *`, just import explicitly whatever you need.